# How to import a function from a file which is outside the directory

Tags: python

```
├── apps
│   ├── package1
│   ├── directory 1
│   │   ├── demo1.py
│   │   └── demo2.py
└   └── test1.py
└   └── test2.py (def function2)
```

here i need to access function2 in test2.py, and use it in demo2.py

it will look like in demo.py file as below

```
from test2 import function2
```

and got an following error
ImportError: cannot import name 'function2' from 'test2'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4383571/15072974).

Comment: Where are you running your code from and what is your PYTHONPATH envirnoment variable set to? Do you have an `__init__.py` file in the `apps` directory?

Comment: maybe `from apps.test2 import function2` ?

Comment: @TomDalton ya i have __init__.py file in apps directory

Comment: @JPG ya i tried that too, but not working

Answer (score 0):

What I have done in situations where I am facing import issues like that. I use `sys` module and append the directory that contains the package I need to import (`test2.py` in your case) to the paths that python will check when looking for files as you try to import.

So something like that

```
import sys
path_to_project = '/path/to/project/apps/'
if path_to_project not in sys.path:
   sys.path.append(path_to_project)

from test2 import function2
```

Comment: tried ..test2 and got an ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: @Srihari Yeah, sorry, I think the relative import method won't work here, the first one worked for me when I tried it though.

Comment: bro can you kindly explain the 1st one related with my example.... kindly use my example keywords and recreate your 1st answer with my example